# Hmm... who can I possibly be?

Tags: cipher, visual, rebus

Can you figure out which person the picture below, most likely, represent?

You're going to do some translation into another language(which language it is, you'll definitely notice :))

[image]

Hint1

> There are 4 different large objects as you can see. What would be the most appropriate names for these objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The person is:

> Albert Einstein

I solved this as follows:

> Take the names of each of the seven large shapes ('moon', 'circle', 'hexagon', 'star'), and for each instance of those remove the letters of the shape name in the positions corresponding to the number of sides of each of the small interior shapes. For example, for the first large shape, a 'moon', remove the second, third, and fourth letters (because the small interior shapes have 2, 3, and 4 sides) to get 'M'.
> When you do this for each of the shapes, you get 'MR ONESTONE'. 'One stone' in German is 'ein stein'. MR EINSTEIN no doubt refers to Albert Einstein.

Comment: Almost forgot this one. Well done!

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that one, and didn't see it until today.